Movie where the protagonist has to repeatedly go to catch a bomber on a train
What is that movie that's set in the future where the lead character  (Jake G ?) is stuck in some virtual reality pod where he repeatedly has to go in and catch the person with the bomb on the train.
Some counselor soldier keeps reminding him to use his training! "This is real time and everyone's going to die unless you can discover who has the bomb", or who's left the bomb and exited the train.
Naturally it takes a whole bunch of times and he keeps re-entering the "situation" sitting across from this girl, over and over--also a well-known actress, but I simply can't visualize her... (Emily Blunt??!)
Ultimately, after trying a billion times he finally puts all the little pieces together from his various attempts and figures the whole thing out, and saves the lives of the people on the train and through some quick thinking and corner-cutting on behalf of the screenwriter he beats the whole "imminent death in the pod.
The movie ends happily with him walking away with his girl (that chick from the train, of course) cavalierly explaining this "victory" to that counselor chick, adenine tossing the mike-piece aside and striding off, arm in arm with his new babe, alive and well. So naturally all's well that ends well.
But, WHAT is that movie called?!? I can remember the movie down to the minute details, but NOT the actors, OR, unfortunately, the TITLE. Help would be appreciated.

Source Code

A soldier wakes up in someone else's body and discovers he's part of an experimental government program to find the bomber of a commuter train. A mission he has only 8 minutes to complete.




